# Can't create a all-day repeated via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0), I try to use Graph API to create a all-day repeated event on my calendar, but the server always responses 400: TimeZoneNotSupportedException.

Is there any wrong in my request?

Here is my request and server response.

**POST** /me/calendars/${one_of_my_calendar_id}/events

Request body:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('6cb879ad-1d01-4aed-bcc5-763e3f51c535')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"BfXylo4WykyAenTZICXL5AABk4B1gA==\"",
    "id": "AAMkADVmMzE2MjY0LTZkOGYtNGI4MS1iNWMxLTljYzg3MWY5MWQxMQBGAAAAAABZMfR36TVMQ6yunaqZPvVRBwAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAACB0WDVAAAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAAGTapeDAAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2019-03-07T10:25:29.5732546Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-03-07T10:25:29.6573241Z",
    "changeKey": "BfXylo4WykyAenTZICXL5AABk4B1gA==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000FB7128DC464BD4010000000000000000100000006176917542798940B4FDBBFBA5B474A6",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 0,
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Repeat-",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": true,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": false,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "free",
    "type": "seriesMaster",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkADVmMzE2MjY0LTZkOGYtNGI4MS1iNWMxLTljYzg3MWY5MWQxMQBGAAAAAABZMfR36TVMQ6yunaqZPvVRBwAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAACB0WDVAAAF9fKWjhbKTIB6dNkgJcvkAAGTapeDAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from text
-->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; }
--></style></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2018-09-25T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2018-09-26T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
        "address": {},
        "coordinates": {}
    },
    "locations": [],
    "recurrence": {
        "pattern": {
            "type": "weekly",
            "interval": 1,
            "month": 0,
            "dayOfMonth": 0,
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "tuesday"
            ],
            "firstDayOfWeek": "monday",
            "index": "first"
        },
        "range": {
            "type": "endDate",
            "startDate": "2018-09-25",
            "endDate": "2019-03-12",
            "recurrenceTimeZone": "",
            "numberOfOccurrences": 0
        }
    },
    "attendees": [],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "MYNAME",
            "address": "MYNAME@MYMAIL.com"
        }
    } }
```

Server response:
http code: 400

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "TimeZoneNotSupportedException",
        "message": "A valid TimeZone value must be specified. The following TimeZone value is not supported: ''.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4833ea1a-3371-4d3e-b28e-193fec18f723",
            "date": "2019-03-07T11:01:36"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try removing `timeZone` reference from the `start`/`end` values?

Comment: @guyarad It doesn't work. I think the problem is 'recurrenceTimeZone', because after I remove it, the server responses 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

You're posting the entire object, including several read-only properties. This will always result in a failure of some kind.

When working with Microsoft Graph (most any REST API actually), you should only submit the properties you want to set:

```
{
  "subject": "Repeat-",
  "isAllDay": true,
  "isReminderOn": false,
  "showAs": "free",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from text\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; }</style></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "recurrence": {
    "pattern": {
      "type": "weekly",
      "interval": 1,
      "daysOfWeek": ["Tuesday"]
    },
    "range": {
      "type": "endDate",
      "startDate": "2018-09-25",
      "endDate": "2019-03-12"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I remove 'recurrenceTimeZone' from my original request body, I can create a all-day event successfully. It seems that the read-only properties in the request is not the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this: note that you have to set the `recurrenceTimeZone` when creating a recurring all day event. Not doing so will result in a 400 without a error message. As with many things, this is not properly documented in the Graph API docs.

Answer (score -1):

After I remove the 'recurrenceTimeZone' from the recurrence/range value, the server responses 200 OK and the new event is be created successfully.

It seems that the recurrenceTimeZone shouldn't be an invalid timezone value.