# Fail to use Graph API to create events which is imported from Google

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I import some events to my Outlook Calendar via an [ics file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FFeG9_y6zTaPTvGMJR-rTLkYNFHQSpln/view?usp=sharing) which were created in Google Calendar. The import is a success, but I find these event objects are different from the other events I create via Outlook UI.

Using Graph Explorer I see that `originalStartTimeZone` and `originalEndTimeZone` in imported event are `tzone://Microsoft/Custom` and `recurrenceTimeZone` is an empty string.

```json
{
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"jQw3WvygBke/Eeuel/y+PAACnR0HFQ==\"",
  "id": "AAMkADU2MzY5ODJlLWI2YjgtNDM5YS1iMWQzLTkxNWFlOTk3MjA3MABGAAAAAAAZitkJ2449ToBFAe4BGzZIBwCNDDda-KAGR78R656X-L48AAKczwuSAACNDDda-KAGR78R656X-L48AAKcz0NjAAA=",
  "createdDateTime": "2019-03-11T12:58:33.1040062Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-03-11T12:58:33.2340999Z",
  "changeKey": "jQw3WvygBke/Eeuel/y+PAACnR0HFQ==",
  "categories": [],
  "originalStartTimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Custom",
  "originalEndTimeZone": "tzone://Microsoft/Custom",
  "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000320000007643616C2D55696401000000336A6C61316A6773666C6B766D70666F766D6D7365686439647240676F6F676C652E636F6D00",
  "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 0,
  "isReminderOn": false,
  "hasAttachments": false,
  "subject": "Every Tue.",
  "bodyPreview": "",
  "importance": "normal",
  "sensitivity": "normal",
  "isAllDay": false,
  "isCancelled": false,
  "isOrganizer": true,
  "responseRequested": false,
  "seriesMasterId": null,
  "showAs": "busy",
  "type": "seriesMaster",
  "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkADU2MzY5ODJlLWI2YjgtNDM5YS1iMWQzLTkxNWFlOTk3MjA3MABGAAAAAAAZitkJ2449ToBFAe4BGzZIBwCNDDda%2FKAGR78R656X%2FL48AAKczwuSAACNDDda%2FKAGR78R656X%2FL48AAKcz0NjAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
  "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
  "responseStatus": {
    "response": "organizer",
    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from text -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-08-13T22:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-08-14T00:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "location": {
    "displayName": "",
    "locationType": "default",
    "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
    "address": {},
    "coordinates": {}
  },
  "locations": [],
  "recurrence": {
    "pattern": {
      "type": "weekly",
      "interval": 1,
      "month": 0,
      "dayOfMonth": 0,
      "daysOfWeek": ["tuesday"],
      "firstDayOfWeek": "monday",
      "index": "first"
    },
    "range": {
      "type": "endDate",
      "startDate": "2018-08-14",
      "endDate": "2018-09-18",
      "recurrenceTimeZone": "",
      "numberOfOccurrences": 0
    }
  },
  "attendees": [],
  "organizer": {
    "emailAddress": {
      "name": "my@gsuite.com",
      "address": "my@gsuite.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Besides, when I use this `event` object as the request body of [Create Event API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0), it returns this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "TimeZoneNotSupportedException",
    "message": "A valid TimeZone value must be specified. The following TimeZone value is not supported: ''.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "69f1a5de-1dbe-4caa-a996-15dc9190380c",
      "date": "2019-03-13T13:37:24"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this a bug with importing `.ics` files or is it a limitation of the API?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you've imported an ICS file in Outlook, why are you also trying to create the same event using Graph?

Comment: To avoid data loss, I write a program to backup Office365 Calendar via Graph API, and also use Graph to restore the backed-up data to Office365 when an accident happens. I find this problem when I test my program. I think the ICS file is correct because it is produced by Google, so that I want know is it a limitation to import ICS file or is it a bug of Graph API?

Comment: If I understand what you're running into, I'm not sure how an ICS is involved here. Are you attempting to use Graph API to import the ICS? If you're trying to simply create an event, what is the payload you're sending to the API?

Comment: No. I use Outlook UI to import the ICS. 
Next, I get the new imported event object from Graph API, and then I take it as the payload and send Create Event API but the server returns error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the same as I provided to your question [Can't create a all-day repeated via Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042532/cant-create-a-all-day-repeated-via-graph-api):

> You're posting the entire object, including several read-only properties. This will always result in a failure of some kind.
>
> When working with Microsoft Graph (most any REST API actually), you should only submit the properties you want to set.

For the event above, you'd send something like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
{
  "isReminderOn": false,
  "subject": "Every Tue.",
  "importance": "normal",
  "sensitivity": "normal",
  "showAs": "busy",
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\r\n<!-- converted from text -->\r\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">&nbsp;</div></span></font>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-08-13T22:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-08-14T00:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "recurrence": {
    "pattern": {
      "type": "weekly",
      "interval": 1,
      "daysOfWeek": ["Tuesday"]
    },
    "range": {
      "type": "endDate",
      "startDate": "2018-08-14",
      "endDate": "2018-09-18"
    }
  }
}
```

For future reference, there is also a published list [supported time zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you forget "recurrenceTimeZone" in the request body. According to Graph API document, it is not a read-only property. However, I receive the same error when I add "recurrenceTimeZone" field in your request body. It seems that the problem is "recurrenceTimeZone" shouldn't be an empty string. I think the Graph API team have to notice this limitation on the document.

Comment: My problem isn't solved. Why the server responses the "recurrenceTimeZone" as an empty string?

Comment: I didn't forget it, I let it out because `recurrenceTimeZone` is _only_ used when that time zone is _different_ than the time zone used for `start` and `end`. When they are the same, you should not provide a `recurrenceTimeZone` value at all.